# Using jQuery ajaxStart and ajaxStop events in different scenarios

Tags: jquery, ajax

For showing loading spinner i used jQuery ajaxStart and ajaxStop event already like this :

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        //some operations ....
    });
```

If i use this code all of my ajax operations have same spinner and code.
I have two buttons with ".btnOne" and ".btnTwo" classes.Both of this buttons loads a page with load() function in jQuery.I want different loading spinners for these ajax operations.
What should i do for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create global variable, for example `clickedButtonClass`, and set it to class of clicked button in button's click handler before calling $ajax(). And then check this variable in `ajaxStart` event handler.

```
var clickedButtonClass;

$('.btnOne').click(function() {
  clickedButtonClass = 'btnOne';
  // do ajax call
  $.ajax({
    ...
  });
});

$('.btnTwo').click(function() {
  clickedButtonClass = 'btnTwo';
  // do ajax call
  $.ajax({
    ///...
  });
});

$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
  if(clickedButtonClass === 'btnOne') {
    //some operations ....
  } else {
    //....
  }

});
```